# Display side by side a datatable and treetable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a problem to display two differents data structures which are `<p:datable>` and `<p:treeTable>`

I want to display the treeTable structure left to dataTable structure side by side.

Like that :

```
|           |           |
| TreeTable | DataTable |
|           |           |
```

For now, I have (by default) :

```
| TreeTable |
-------------
| DataTable |
```

I have already tried to work with layout structure but the result is not what I want.

This is what I tried :

```
<p:layout fullPage="true">
    <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="50%">
        <p:treeTable>
        </p:treeTable>
    </p:layoutUnit>
    <p:layoutUnit position="center" size="50%">
        <p:dataTable>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
```

In fact, this is the nearest of what I want but the two structures are seperated and I want them not seperated like in my example.

Comment: Start by learning basic html and css. Totally not jsf/primefaces related (there is **no** 'default'). See also [mcve]

Comment: While I agree that OP should stick to the basics of HTML and CSS, I also think that this is a valid question if focused on the p:layout and p:layoutUnit components.

Comment: @Kukeltje I'm sorry I wasn't precise enough, I can use CSS to do that but I was wondering if can do it without. That's why I was using layout.

Comment: I think the `size` attribute doesn't support value in `%`.

Comment: Why without css? That is what it is for! You can maybe add a lot of html or some javascript to achieve it, but that would be 'hacks'

Answer (score 0):

There is asolution using html, you can use `panelGrid` with `style="display: block"` to place one `panelGrid` next to the other. You have a `<p:datable>` and a `<p:treeTable>`, so you have to put 2 panelGrids :

```
<h:panelGrid id="panelQualification" columns="3" >
    <h:panelGrid style="height: 300px;  display: block" >
        <p:dataTable>                                    
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:panelGrid>


    <h:panelGrid style="height: 300px;  display: block" >
        <p:dataTable>                                
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGrid>
```